# Format of SMS PDU in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

When we are receiving sms messages in BroadcastReceiver, we initially receive them as an array of PDUs. I know that there is a format for GSM sms PDUs described in the GSM specification and I know how to decode such gsm PDUs.

I'd like to know: is the format of Android PDUs the same as in the GSM specification? If not then what is the format of android sms PDUs? Is the format of android PDUs different for GSM and for CDMA phones?

Thank you in advance.

PS: I know that there is the SmsMessage class for decoding PDUs, but I want to decode them myself, that is why I am asking this question.

Answer (score 2):

> is the format of Android PDUs the same as in the GSM specification? If not then what is the format of android sms PDUs? Is the format of android PDUs different for GSM and for CDMA phones?

You will have to determine that for yourself by examining the source code for the classes that parse the PDUs:

- **[com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/gsm/SmsMessage.java&q=SmsMessage%20package%3aandroid.git.kernel.org&sa=N&cd=3&ct=rc)**
- **[com.android.internal.telephony.cdma.SmsMessage](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/cdma/SmsMessage.java&q=SmsMessage%20package%3aandroid.git.kernel.org&d=6)**